# TYPO3 DCE Section Element

Tags: typo3, sections

I build a DCE content element where users can add new products for different categories. So I use sections as follow:

[image: Section]

Problem is that I can add only up to 34 new elements. After that I can create new elements but TYPO3 is not saving that. So it is not possible to add new products
Are there any limitations or something else? Or had someone the same problem?

Thank you
Mando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the php settings, then to max_input_vars and increase the limit/number to 2000. It will work!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there is no limit on the number of flex section container elements.
Have a look at your webserver logs, maybe some POST values are dropped, and try to increase the size of the underlying DB field, maybe thats cut off.

Comment: i did not find anything..no dropped POST's and no limited DB fields.